# question pool based flash quiz

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I want to build a flash based quiz app that will present users with questions and based on responses will pick next question from the pool. Any ideas on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho XMLList class is the best choice
e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
    <question id="1" onright="2" onwrong="3" answer="4" text="calcutate 2*2"/>
    <question id="2" onright="4" onwrong="1" answer="25" text="calcutate 5*5"/>
    <question id="3" onright="2" onwrong="1" answer="yes" text="just mistyped?"/>
    <question id="4" onright="5" onwrong="?" answer="?" text="?"/>
</data>
```

it really depend on the quiz structure

Comment: you can define IDs of next questions in parameters of answer tag

Comment: but i'm still not sure how do i achieve that little bit of AI in the program that if question 'A' is correct move to question 'B' or if it is wrong then move to 'a-1'? What will be the structure of the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need some kind of array.

It would contain the questions (accessed by an ID number) and answers. To each answer another question ID would be attached so that when the user answers with that answer, the question with specified ID would appear.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i want to make it dynamic so that questions pool could be defined let's say in an xml file will be pulled in at runtime.

Comment: Same... The parsing is your thing. The array will just be the core of it - it's on you how you make that array.